# «Побеждает команда, первой набравшая шесть очков»

Tags: окончания

«Первой набравшая.» Верны ли окончания?

Answer (score 3):

Окончания верные: **Побеждает команда, первой набравшая шесть очков.**

Сравнить: Команда **первой** набрала шесть очков.

Первой — это дуплексив, второстепенный член с двойной связью. Он согласуется с существительным *команда* в роде, а Т. падеж  (связь управление) задает  причастие (глагол).